# Crystal reports: how to conditionally suppress sections

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having difficulty suppressing a group header if another group header is blank/suppressed.

Originally I had a layout as follows:

Group Header a - contains client details
Group Header b - contains a subreport that showed details of the incoming calls from client that were received in the last 24 hours.

If the sub report in group header b was blank (because no calls had been received in the last 24 hours), my report was still showing the client details in group header a. 
I can suppress the group header b section if the subreport is blank, but cannot work out how to suppress group header a if group header b is blank/suppressed.

After reading various other discussions, I understood that if you want to suppress a section when a subreport is blank, then the subreport would need to be in a section before the section you want to suppress.

So, I changed my layout as follows:

Group Header a - contains sub report showing details of calls in last 24 hours (sub report is suppressed if blank, and group header a is suppressed if blank)
Group Header b - contains client details
Group Header c - contains same subreport showing calls received in last 24 hours

So what I now need to work out is, how do I suppress group header b and c if group header a is suppressed?!

Any help would be greatfully received.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to check record count of sub report, if it is zero then suppress the group using conditional suppress formula. So basically in your group query somewhere you must have field which keeps the count of records in sub report.

1. Right Click on section
2. Section Expert
3. Suppress No Drill
4. Click x-2 formula editor
5. if {count} = 0 then true else false
   Where {count} is the field having total records for that group

Hope this helps you!